# Android: Service Still Running after Logout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, logout

So below is my logout for my Android app, and I look at my logcat and I see that a service is still running (BeaconService"), and I can't figure out why this happens, do I need to do anything to the onPostExecute() or onDestory() methods in my activity class?

```
public void logOut(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MainActivity.sp.edit();
    editor.putString("token", null );
    editor.putString("username", null);
    editor.commit();

    currentUser = null;

    Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(main);
}
```

Comment: how do you start you're service?

Comment: you start MainActivity on logOut()!? The basic way is contex.stopService(intent)